# Getting Issue while running the React Native Application on xCode 14.1

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have tried to run the React native Application on xCode. Getting the  error - 'Library not found for - IBVLinearGradient'.

Mac OS - Apple M1 chip
React native version - 0.66.3

xCode version - 14.1[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieJax.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5GdE.png)

I have tried de-integrating the pods and installing again but still the same problem exists.

Comment: probably you can check solutions from this brunch https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/554